# ChromeCast: Chrome sample project not running

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast, chromecast

I am following the setup instructions here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome step by step.

I have my Google Drive hosting folder here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByI6ac75SrewSE1odEdBMm1fNk0&usp=sharing

I set my URL (for my application in the developer console) to https://googledrive.com/host/0ByI6ac75SrewSE1odEdBMm1fNk0/receiver.html

However, when I run my chromehellotext: https://googledrive.com/host/0ByI6ac75SrewSE1odEdBMm1fNk0/chromehellotext.html
I get this error in the console: "onError: {"code":"session_error","description":"NOT_FOUND","details":null}" and my Chromecast will not connect when I hit the carriage return and select my Chromecast.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to publish this sample of yours and see if then you can cast?  If yes, it's something to do with whitelisting.  How do you name your device?

Comment: My device's name is "Den."  Tried publishing and now I get : onError: {"code":"timeout","description":"Timeout at extension","details":null}

Comment: @Nightly Nexus is your application published or unpublished?

Answer (score 6):

Checking the box for sending the serial number to google solved this problem for me as well.  It took me a few minutes to figure out where this box is so that I could check it.  I had to download the chromecast setup application and then let it discover my device, select it, and click settings.  The checkbox is in the settings.

Comment: I struggled with this error for hours, and waiting didn't do it for me. I did checked this, did a factory reset, checked again, reboot, and now it's working.

Answer (score 5):

It can take [up to 6 hours to publish your receiver app](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver). As the docs suggest, all you need to do is restart your Chromecast to force the device to reload it's configuration data. I was having this same issue and a restart was all I needed.

Comment: I am not publishing it, though.  I have entered my Chromecast serial number on the developer console, and it says, "Ready for Testing."

Comment: I'm having the same issues. I also tried a factory reset, checked the serial number box, and reboot.  It still wasn't able to connect. I've tried several applications. I published one application, but I haven't waited 6 hours.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me as mine wasn't published as well. The answer below about sending Google your serial ID in Chromecast's settings is what fixed it for me.

Comment: To be clear, the 6-hour delay applies not only to publishing but for running the app in debug mode as well.  Additionally, it took far longer than 6 hours for mine to "publish".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your receiver app is loading the `cast_receiver.js` javascript file as well as starting an instance of the `castReceiverManager`.

I was seeing that same timeout message before I did that.  My initial receiver code was just static HTML, but apparently that's not good enough.

The following, in my receiver's `index.html` did the trick for me:

`<`script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js">`<`/script>

`<`script>

```
  window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
  window.castReceiverManager.start();
```

`<`/script>

(copied from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver)